# Ionic App - No Internet Access

Tags: android, cordova

Ive built a small mobile Android 6 app with ionic and Phonegap. This isnt my first Hybrid app, but is my first with Ionic. The app calls a php file that queries a MySQL DB and returns some info to the view. The app works as needed both online and locally, but does not have internet access after Ive built it via PhoneGap. None of my styles are loaded as well as the info returned from the PHP call. I have published the app via PhoneGap and Im testing via a Samsung galaxy 5; I developed everything on a Mac.

I have the Cordova whitelist plugin installed as needed and added the necessary permissions to the manifest, but I need another set of eyes to look over this.

Here is my config.xml file:

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.testrest902325" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>NAME</name>
  <description>
       DESCRIPTION
    </description>
  <author email="name@name.edu" href="http://example.com.com/">
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
<access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
</widget>
```

and here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.testrest902325" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: have you tried to set permissions from the config.xml file?
Try this when you can:
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

Comment: @DataGuy Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). Where are your assets (html,css,javascript,etc)? are they online or they on the device? **Please answer this in your POST**

Comment: @DataGuy also, you don't need to make changes or fixes to AndroidManifest.xml (except in special cases). And Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App?  What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? What platform are you developing on? Windows, MacOS? Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: Everything you have requested has been added to the post. thanks

Comment: @DataGuy when you respond you need to use my handle in the response, or I don't see it. Like this @  jessemonroy650

Answer (score 3):

I had very similar issue; even after installing whitelist plugin and having necessary permissions, my app never connected to my web service.

Then I thought to give a try including whitelist plugin in config.xml. So, in my project folder I ran the following command which had updated my config.xml

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist --save
```

After that the APK generated by my automated build system, was connecting to my web service.

Comment: Thanks Chandru, it worked for me, Btw I had to remove the android platform and then add again before build.